# PHP Imagick Segementation Fault

Tags: php, imagick

I have a cheap $5/mo server, 1G ram processing some images for my website. Very rarely I will encounter a segmentation fault with PHP Imagick when writing a GIF image to disk.

I have set a memory limit on the console command hoping PHP would catch the issue first and throw an exception that I can properly handle, but this did not work.

The particular issue is certain GIF images cause it to crash at this line of code:

```
     echo 'Writing images to disk.' . PHP_EOL;
     $file = $img->writeImages($imageOnDIsk, true);//crashes here
     echo 'Finished writing images to disk.' . PHP_EOL;
```

The specific GIF is an adult related GIF so I am not sure if I can share it.

Here is my server logs:

> `Setting memory limit.
>   Pulling URL: https://i.redd.it/gyvc8t9xdvb41.gif
>   Coalescing Images
>   Done Coalescing Images
>   Processing regular image.
>   Not comic.
>   Deleting temp image on disk.
>   Writing images to disk.
>   Segmentation fault (core dumped)`

Seems this images width * height * bit depth * frames is using up more than 1G of memory. Need to detect this before hand.

Answer (score 1):

A `Segmentation fault` is a generic operating system level error. As an end-user of PHP you neither have any control over it nor can you fix it. It is something that needs to be fixed at the php-src level (in this case specifically the imagick extension code).

Simply put this potentially a bug in **PHP itself** not in your code.

---

Things you can do is file a [bug report with PHP](https://bugs.php.net). And provide a [backtrace](https://bugs.php.net/bugs-generating-backtrace.php) along with the bug report to have one of the extension developers look into fixing this.

Comment: So what can I do to look into fixing this? I really don't want to upgrade this little server to 2G as it'll cost $10/mo instead of $5.

Comment: You can't fix it. Not unless you fix the imagick extension code, which is written in C. You can file a [bug report](https://bugs.php.net) with PHP, however. See [generating a gdb backtrace](https://bugs.php.net/bugs-generating-backtrace.php) for details on how to submit a good bug report.